Jetstream photo url change from 127.0.0.1 to virtual host
Anyone have a issue like me? Before when first install Jetstream, the photo is working, but now when im upload the image, the upload is success but the image its not showing, when i see it the image on new tab, its show link using virtual host from laragon, example Dev.test
When i see the link Jetstream photo url its become to dev.test/storage/xxxxxxx
and on app its not showing or img crash logo when im using php artisan serve or 127.0.0.1:8000, why? Before when first installaion Jetstream its working like normal.
